# Method overriding with throws clause runtime behaviour

Tags: java, overriding

To explain my question please check java code below.

```
public interface Parent {
    public void method();
}

public class Child implements Parent {
    public void method() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

As you all will say, this will not compile, since Child class' method declares exception which is not specified in interface.
How about runtime behavior ? I have encountered a condition where this combination do not throw exception at runtime and method works fine.
Is that right behaviour, (I mean this method signature with exception clause control is done at compile time and at runtime throws clause not considered as method signature) or I am missing something here ?

I see my question is not clear.

Let me try again;

The class combination above work at runtime, and of course to compile Child class correct version of Parent class is used.

Comment: The question is quite unclear to me. Can you explain it a bit differently.

Comment: better now ? Need further explanation ?

Answer (score 1):

There will never be a runtime if compilation fails. You can try throwing RuntimeException instead of Exception(which includes catched Exceptions as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the method declaration in the interface to clearly indicate that the method may throw some typed exception, or your implementations can always throw a `RuntimeException` specific to your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So at compile time the rule is in enforced - the rule that when you override a method you cannot have the method throw a more general exception than the super method (the method you're overriding).

However, as I think you've discovered, this constraint is only enforced by the compiler and is not checked again at runtime. If you change the super class exception so that it is more general, compile the code, extract the compiled sub class and put it aside, then change the super class back to the less general exception and extract that class. Then run these two classes together your code will run.

The issue here is that some constraints are only enforced at compile time, others are enforced at compile time - some can only be enforced at runtime. And the reason constraints are not checked again at runtime when they've already been checked at compile time is for performance.